# How to programatically set joint friction torque?

Tags: friction

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a car model in Gazebo. Each of the 4 wheels has a continuous joint with friction torque in the urdf file. I want to set the friction torque value dynamically in the source code (instead of hardcoded in the urdf) to simulate the brake pedal. How can I do this? Can I use some kind of Gazebo plugin?

P.S I cannot manually apply a reverse torque to the joint because the car will never truly stop if I push the brake pedal. Instead it will shake forward and backward with a low speed forever.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16442/how-to-programatically-set-joint-friction-torque?/) by [quanke0801](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3365/quanke0801/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use a model plugin to set the joint friction. Here are [tutorials for creating plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=write_plugin) tutorials. I think you're interested in the [model plugin tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin).

The `Load` method is given a `physics::ModelPtr`. Call `GetJoint(name)` where `name` is an `std::string` with the name of the joint you would like to set friction on. This will return a `physics::JointPtr`. On this pointer call `SetParam("friction", 0, 1.0)`. The second argument is the joint axis. `0` says use the first axis; revolute joints only have one. The last parameter is the minimum torque required to move the joint in newton-meters.

Note, `SetParam` is special in that the third parameter has to be exactly the right type. The compiler can't automatically cast it for you. In this case `"friction"` is a double. If the third parameter is `1.0f` or `1` instead of `1.0` the call will fail.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [quanke0801](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3365/quanke0801/) on 2017-06-15**:
Thanks! One follow-up question: any ideas on how to pass argument from source code to this plugin? Different cars will apply brake torque on different set of joints, but I'd like to use a same plugin. Also the required friction torque is computed in the source code. Can I use ros parameter server to set the joint names and use a subscriber in the plugin to get the required friction?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-06-15**:
Sure, make the arguments part of the SDF for each instance of the plugin. SDF allows aribtrary XML tags to be passed to a plugin`<plugin name="my_fancy_plugin_instance" filename="libMyFancyPlugin.so"><max_brake_torque>12345</max_brake_torque></plugin>`. See the random velocity plugin for an example http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_random_velocity

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-06-15**:
Ah, sneaky edit about ROS parameters! I believe you can initialize a ROS node inside the plugin, and from there do whatever you like through the ROS API. The plugins will need a way of identifying which which ROS param belongs to them, but the SDF arguments gives a way to name the instances.